# Hide sheet on click?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a VERY new learner to VBA trying to decypher functions and build an interactive file. With help from one user here (who will certainly know who he is ;)), I could learn quite a few things.

Now I'm stuck at one ridiculous piece of code : I want to 1/unhide a sheet, 2/go to that sheet and 3/re-hide the sheet when the user selects the "back to the start page-button". 
So I made this code :

```
Sub FRtoEN()
'
' FRtoEN Macro
' Emmène au Glossaire FR ==> EN
'
    Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = True
    Sheets("Synthèse_FR&EN").Select

End Sub
```

and it works well. But I cannot find out how to tell excel in VBA-language that I want it to re-hide the tab once the user is done and clicks the exit button.

Could you help me?

Comment: If `Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = True` *unhides* the sheet, then change `True` to `False` to *hide* it.

Comment: If there's a button on the sheet `synthèse_FR&EN` and you want the sheet to hide when clicking the button, you should make the same macro which sets `.Visible = False` instead of `True` and attach it to that button.

Answer (score 3):

Ferndiando's answer is brilliant when you want to have one button where you first show the hidden sheet and next time you click *on the same* button it hide the same sheet.

Making one button to show a sheet and another button to hide the same sheet, do the following;

In the first button you will make the code visible:

```
Sub FRtoEN()
'
' FRtoEN Macro
' Emmène au Glossaire FR ==> EN
'
    Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = True
    Sheets("Synthèse_FR&EN").Activate

End Sub
```

In the second button that which will take the user back to the "Main Page" you can add this code:

```
Sub StartPage()

Sheets("Start Page").Activate 'First go to Start page
Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = False 'Then hide the sheet they currently visited, that makes the experience a little bit more "working in background"

End Sub
```

---

If I assume you use this "back to the start page-button" for several sheets, you could hide other sheets too every time someone goes to start page.

```
Sub StartPage()

Sheets("Start Page").Activate 'First go to Start page
Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = False
Sheets("synthèse_FR&DE").Visible = False 'Example 1 - No matter which sheet you visit, it will hide this sheets.
Sheets("synthèse_FR&SP").Visible = False 'Example 2 - No matter which sheet you visit, it will hide this sheets.

End Sub
```

---

---

If you want the code to perform things on hidden sheets, while they still are hidden for the user (for example background filtering/calculations/copy data etc..) this will give the user a smooth experience:

```
Sub StartPage()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn of all visual updates the macro does. Macro works in background without showing every step visually in Excel.
Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = True 'Unhide the sheet you want to work at.

'Do some filtering stuff // copy stuff 

Sheets("synthèse_FR&EN").Visible = False 'Re-hide the sheet again.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Turn ON all visual updates the macro does. Macro now works and shows every step visually in Excel.

End Sub
```

:)

Comment: Many thanks to you all!! I applied following code to my language buttons:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/djs6ob5t3mtigv0/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202018-11-01%2017.35.16.png?dl=0

Comment: I tried to use the code <pre><code> to indent this as code, or the CTRK+L keys, but it didn't work... Certainly doing something wrong!

Comment: Looks good :), nice solution. I didn't follow on your second comment. Do you mind to elaborate :P

Answer (score 2):

If i understood your question you can use this code:

```
Sub myButton()
'Hide and Show Sheet2 with same button
' you can change the sheet name as you prefer

If (Sheets("Sheet2").Visible) Then ' control if the sheet is visible
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False ' hide sheet2 because before was showed
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select          ' select sheet1
Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True  ' show sheet2 because before was hidden
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select          'select sheet2
End If

End Sub
```

I hope this help you.